# Visiting Shani Temple

Tags: belief

Can we visit Shani temple after visiting the main Deity?

We went to Batu caves and had darshan of Lord Subramanya. While coming down we saw another temple which we thought was of a goddess but it was a Shani Temple.

Somehow I'm disturbed that I should not have visited that. Is there any thing in the scriptures forbidding this?

Comment: As far as I know, there's absolutely nothing wrong with worshipping Shani or going to Shani temples.  It's true that Shani is in charge of dispensing good and bad fortune, but worshipping him doesn't attract bad fortune or anything.

Comment: Related [Why women are not allowed to offer prayers at Shingnapur Shani Temple?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9661/3500)

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, there is no harm in visiting Shani temple. It is similar to visiting other God or Goddesses temples.

Though, in some places there will be conditions like you need to visit a temple after visiting the other Gods temple. For example, "[Sakshi ganapathi](http://www.srisailamonline.com/sakshi-ganapathi.html)"

> The traditional beliefs is that the Ganapathi in this temple keeps regular account of all the pilgrims to tender “Sakshyam” (evidence) of their visit to this kshetram and so named as Sakshi Ganapathi.

So, there could be traditions to follow but there is no harm if you don't follow those traditions and visit the temple.

Comment: Link not found for Shakshi Ganpati

Comment: @Pandya updated. Thanks