# References from scriptures about prohibition of menstruating women from temples, pujas etc

Tags: rituals, women, dharma-shastras

I am doing a research on this topic and searching for references for it. I am especially looking for references to Ashaucha related to menses, any specific guideline regarding what actions are prohibited during menses due to ashaucha like doing puja, visiting temples etc. And any elaboration on the ashaucha related to menses, the reasons behind the prohibition.

I am looking for references from scriptures, it may be Dharma shastras, Puranas, Tantras, or any other Hindu text.

Thank you

Comment: The Sabarimala issue is completely separate, so you should take it out of your question.  Sabarimala doesn't just prohibit women who are currently menstruating, it prohibits all women who are capable of menstruating, i.e. between puberty and menopause.  The reason for that is Ayyapa's vow of Brahmacharya.

Comment: Yes. I am looking for references from any Stala purana as well for this practice in Sabarimala and that Ayyappa was Brahmachari and hence the case. I would be glad if you could give any reference, any points to all the questions I have asked. Thanks.

Comment: Well, a question has already been posted about the Sabarimala practice: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10116/36 So you should remove that part from your question.

Comment: Okay. Removed that portion.

Comment: @NithinSridhar You can go through my [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15519/4732) answer.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks for the link. After asking my question, I had continued my research and have written a detailed 6-part article on the same. You can read first part here (links to others within the link)-http://indiafacts.org/hindu-view-menstruation-ii-menstruation-ashaucha/